# iOS app Certificaction and ad hoc testing

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I work for a company developing their iPad app. None in the company is a technological geek to handle Xcode app deployment themselves. So for now, we do this:

1. I develop the app.
2. Create an ad hoc testing version and share the `.ipa` file with them.
3. They test and then I make a distribution version for further release.

What I want to establish as a permanent solution is

1. I develop and share the Xcode archive
2. They make all different versions for testing and release.

However I have been largely unsuccessful in doing so: for creating the archive, I have to sign/certify with my development profile. They could deploy it further from Xcode archive to an `.ipa` file, using their distribution certificate. However, they can not install it on their devices. I believe mainly because the development version requires my certificate/profile to be enabled on their devices :(.

Is there a way out? I need to provide them an archive which they could further sign and do whatever they want to do (either test on whatever devices they want to or release).

Thanks,

Nikhil

Comment: And why are you not signing with their distribution certificate ?

Comment: don't I need their private keys installed on my machine to do so? I initially thought so, but these criticality's made me take aback :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manage the device identifiers where you are deploying the device, you could use:

1)  [TestFlightApp.com](http://testflightapp.com) (although I don't know what the current status of their offerings are -- since they've been acquired by Apple -- but they still have a "Sign Up" link on the top of their home page).

or

2) [Apple's Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), which allows you to "Distribute In-house Apps".

Comment: So for this simple thing, I have to pay Apple? :(... that's quite discouraging

Comment: #2 you do, yes. I think TestFlight is still free.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign application using their distribution certificate.

To do so c'est have to send you a p12 export of the certificate, the p12 contains the private key of the one creating the certificate and the certificate.

To export a certificate :

1. Go to the keychain access
2. Right click on the certificate
3. click export